# An algorithm where I find the min and max element value and then do it again after removing those elements

Tags: java, algorithm

I have the methods to find the smallest and largest value, and also to place them where they need to be. I also have a method to call those methods, and shrink to a subarray. The problem is, even though it is sorting, I can't print the array once I've moved into the subarray. Please help, there has to be a better way and I've banged my head against the wall for a while now.

```
package mySort;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MyAlg {
    public static int findSmall(int[] input){
        int sm = input[0];
        for(int i = 0; i <= input.length - 1; i++){
            if(sm < input[i])
                sm = input[i];
        }
        input[0] = sm;
        return sm;
    }
    public static int findLarge(int[] input){
        int lg = input[input.length -1];
        for(int i = 0; i <= input.length - 1; i++){
            if(input[i] > lg)
                lg = input[i];
        }
        input[input.length -1] = lg;
        return lg;
    }
    public static int[] sort(int[] input){
        findSmall(input);
        findLarge(input);
        for(int i = 0; i<= (input.length - 1) / 2; i++){
            int[] tmp = Arrays.copyOfRange(input, i + 1, input.length - 2 );
            findSmall(tmp);
            findLarge(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to sort this way? If you are trying to sort the contents of an array it is much easier to make a same sized array and copy there, only going in one direction (max or min depending on how you want to sort).

Comment: you never do anything with the values returned by `findSmall` and `findLarge` .

Comment: It's a school assignment worded as below:                                                       Consider an algorithm that sorts an array of n elements by finding the smallest and largest elements and then exchanges those elements with the elements in the first and last positions in the array. Then the size of the array is reduced by two elements after excluding the two elements that are already in the proper positions, and the process is repeated on the remaining part of the array until the entire array is sorted.

Comment: this is not sorting anything bro, i printed out the outcome of your methods. the array that comes out is not sorted

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are required to use an array or not, but if you are free to use whatever data structure you like I would recommend a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). This data structure implements SortedSet which means as the objects are added they are sorted already for you. Then you can use methods such as

- first() - to return the lowest value
- last() - to return the highest value

Then you could remove those highest and lowest elements or use these methods after that

- ceiling(int) - highest number lower than given int
- floor(int) - smallest number higher than given int

Lmk if you need more help or just need an implementation for an array.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your code is quite flawed, so I just rewrote everything. The below code will sort any int[] by placing the smallest int in the input array in the left most unfilled position of a new array and placing the biggest in the right most unfilled position of a new array, until the new array is a sorted version of the input array. Enjoy

```
private static int[] sort(int[] input) {

    //create an empty array the same size as input
    int[] sorted = new int[input.length];

    //create another empty array the same size as input
    int[] temp = new int[input.length];

    // copy input into temp
    for (int i = 0; i <= (input.length - 1); i++) {
        temp[i] = input[i];
    }

    //create variables to tell where to put big and small
    //in the sorted array
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = sorted.length - 1;

    //create variables to hold the biggest and smallest values in 
    //input. For now we'll give them the values of the first element 
    //in input, they'll change
    int big = input[0];
    int small = input[0];

    // sort

    //sort the array as you described
    while (temp.length != 0) {
        //find the biggest and smallest value in temp
        big = findBig(temp);
        small = findSmall(temp);

        //place the biggest at the end of the sorted array
        //and place the smallest at the beginning of the sorted array
        sorted[leftIndex] = small;
        sorted[rightIndex] = big;

        //move the left index of the sorted array up, so we don't over write
        //the element we put in on the next iteration, same for the right index to,
        //but down
        leftIndex++;
        rightIndex--;

        if(temp.length != 1){
        //remove the biggest and smallest values from the temp array
        temp = removeElement(temp, big);
        temp = removeElement(temp, small);
        }else{
            //only remove one element in the event the array size is odd
            //also not at this point leftIndex == rightIndex as it will be the last 
            //element
            temp = removeElement(temp, big);
        }

        //repeat, until the temp array is empty

    }

    // print out the content of the sorted array
    for (int i = 0; i <= (sorted.length - 1); i++) {
        System.out.println("Index " + i + ": " + sorted[i]);
    }

    //return the sorted array
    return sorted;
}

//find the smallest number in an int array and return it's value
private static int findSmall(int[] input) {

    int smallest = input[0];

    for (int i = 0; i <= (input.length - 1); i++) {
        if (smallest > input[i]) {
            smallest = input[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}

//find the biggest value in an int array and return it's value
private static int findBig(int[] input) {

    int biggest = input[0];

    for (int i = 0; i <= (input.length - 1); i++) {
        if (biggest < input[i]) {
            biggest = input[i];
        }
    }
    return biggest;
}

//remove an element from an int array, based on it's value
private static int[] removeElement(int[] input, int elementValue) {

    //create a temp array of size input - 1, because there will be one less element 
    int[] temp = new int[input.length - 1];

    //create variable to tell which index to remove, set to 0 to start
    //will change unless it is right
    int indexToRemove = 0;

    //find out what the index of the element you want to remove is
    for (int i = 0; i <= (input.length - 1); i++) {
        if (input[i] == elementValue) {
            //assign the value to
            indexToRemove = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    //variable that says if we've hit the index we want to remove
    boolean removeFound = false;

    for (int i = 0; i <= (input.length - 1); i++) {

        //check if we are at the index we want to remove
        if (indexToRemove == i) {
            //if we are say so
            removeFound = true;
        }

        //done if we aren't at the index we want to remove
        if (i != indexToRemove && removeFound == false) {
            //copy input to temp as normal
            temp[i] = input[i];
        }

        //done if we've hit the index we want to remove
        if (i != indexToRemove && removeFound == true) {
            //note the -1, as we've skipped one and need the to decrement
            //note input isn't decremented, as we need the value as normal
            //note we skipped the element we wanted to delete
            temp[i - 1] = input[i];
        }

    }

    //return the modified array that doesn't contain the element we removed
    //and it is 1 index smaller than the input array
    return temp;
}

}
```

Also, I'd place all of these methods into a class Sort, but I wrote it in this way to mimic the way you wrote your code to a certain extent. This would require you to create a getSorted method, and I'd also change the sort method to a constructor if it was placed in a class Sort.

Comment: Thank you for the help on getting it printing with just the large! However, my professor is requiring us to find the smallest value AND the largest value, while being able to print.

Comment: I edited the code I provided, I can't recall if it notifies you, but this comment should

Answer (score 0):

I have written an algorithm to solve your this problem. Using divide and conquer we can solve this problem effectively. Comparing each value to every one the smallest and the largest value can be found. After cutting off 2 values the first one(smallest) and the last one (largest) the new unsorted array will be processed with the same algorithm to find the smallest and largest value.

You can see my algorithm in [GitHub] (https://github.com/jabedhossain/SortingProblem/)

Although its written in C++, the comments should be enough to lead you through.